# jQuery hasclass structure

Tags: jquery, design-patterns

See this link: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4&fn=jQuery.fn.hasClass

```
var className = " " + selector + " ";
....
(" " + this[i].className + " ")
```

Many times in my career I've had uses for functions that trim whitespace, I have never seen a reason to add whitespace.  What is the purpose of the empty strings being prepended and appended to these variables.

Comment: I think that's because, it's possible to has more than one class with space separative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have an element with the classes `foo` and `fooBar`, adding the extra spaces at the start and end, ensures you always have spaces sourrding the name of each class.
This allows you to search for `" foo "` and avoid matching `fooBar`.

Off: I moved this to an answer so that the question could be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Classes in HTML are space-separated in the markup. Rather than performing a string split, followed by searching through the array, the spaces are added so that even if that class is the only class applied to that element, it will still be matched by the selector.

Comment: Also, if for example you have `foo` and `fooBar` adding the extra spaces means you that if you search for `foo` you can actually search for `" foo "` and avoid matching against `fooBar`

Comment: Now that's the right answer, you should have put that as an answer.  I did some testing and saw no differences (in chrome) about using indexOf with or without the spaces.  Your explanation makes more sense to me.